# Using Python to pull data into S4

Tags: python

The twittertopiccount example provided with S4 is written in Java.

The documentation here: http://docs.s4.io/cookbook/building_your_application.html says nothing about using other languages.

Is it possible to write an application in Python, to read data from a file and send the data to S4?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use many langs which have JSON proceeding feature. read  [this](http://docs.s4.io/manual/client_usage.html)